# how to add server address instead of URL in facebook Valid OAuth Redirect URIs?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I want to add server address as the redirect URl in the facebook Valid OAuth Redirect URIs. I am using the IP address at the moment and I am using http://xx.189.xx.123/login/facebook/callback as the server url. I am unable to add this url as the redirect url. Anybody can help ?

Comment: You can not use IP addresses, it has to be an actual domain name.

Comment: will it work with a localhost domain  like for xampp server ?

Comment: Yes; the important stuff regarding the redirect login flow happens in your browser - so only that will need to be able to resolve the domain, nothing from the outside.

Comment: No I tried to add http://netball.laravel.dev2/public/login/facebook/callback and http://localhost/public/login/facebook/callback but it does not seem to working as well https://prnt.sc/q5jk6m

Comment: It needs to match your app domain, you can not have the same app running on multiple different domains for login purposes.

Comment: okay so you mean for different domain I need to create different app ?

Comment: Create a test app for your local development. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

Comment: okay it seems a better idea.